# Brevity with Prose Rhythm

Tags: style, voice

Along with the book "The Elements of Style", many style guides often emphasize the value of concision, but either leave out a discussion of prose rhythm or say it is something to have in your writing "all things being equal".

Prose rhythm is the quality of a piece's voice, determined by the placement of syllables stressed and syllables non-stressed, and by the placement of sound as well as silence, their places determined by syntax and choice of words.

My question is this: Can an author accomplish rhythmic effects, also observing brevity? This is a question to those in agreement with the use of rhythmic effects. On this please expound if you are able.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're asking whether a prose author can achieve rhythm, while at the same time being brief/concise? My quick answer would be yes... sentence length can vary (creating rhythm), while also being concise.

Comment: Yes, that's sort of what I'm asking, but in the question, which involves something more, I've included a succinct description of prose rhythm, things I would like answerers to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Guides are not hard and fast rules.

I'd say the brevity advised by so many guides is relative. Sentences do not have to be short, but it is preferable that a sentence makes its point in as few words as possible. The words we are advised to cut are only the ones deemed unnecessary. Craft and voice is partly knowing when to include multiple clauses into a single sentence, or break them up into shorter ones, giving you opportunity to create rhythm. Similarly, using adjectives can affect the rhythm of a sentence as well as illustrate.

As an example, in the paragraph above:

"Sentences do not have to be short, but it is preferable that a sentence makes its point in a few words as possible."

I could have split this into two brief conflicting sentences, removing the word "but". I chose combine them because I believe the paragraph reads better as a result.

Comment: Can I add extra words here and there to accomplish rhythm?

Comment: You have editied your question 22 times since I offered the above answer, so I'm assuming you are finding your own answer in the process ;-)